# why C++ recognizes an uninitialized raw-pointer as true?

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, segmentation-fault

Why the following code produces a **seg-fault**

```
//somewhere in main
    ...
    int *pointer;
    if(pointer)
        cout << *pointer;
    ...
```

But slightly changed following code doesn't

```
//somewhere in main
    ...
    int *pointer = nullptr;
    if(pointer)
        cout << *pointer;
    ...
```

the question is what in C++ makes an uninitialized pointer true - and leads to a **crash**

Comment: Because C++ doesn't initialize your variables for you. Because that may be a cost you don't have to pay for.  So the first line, the pointer can have ANY value and point to random memory locations. Also if a pointer is a nullptr then if used in an if statement it evaluates to false;

Comment: Reading uninitialised memory is *undefined behaviour*, which is what you invoke in the first case. Side note: In some cases your programme might *not* crash – just by accident the (garbage!) address in the pointer *might* be (from operating system view – *not* from C++ view!) valid *and* accessible, then you won't experience the segmentation fault – and these are errors pretty ugly to find! So be happy about the crash...

Comment: The later one won't crash but prints nothing because the `if` condition is false

Comment: Side note: If you skip the `if` test in second case and just print out the pointer value then you most likely get another segmentation fault. In any case, dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour as well.

Comment: Accessing the value of an uninitialised pointer gives undefined behaviour.  So `int *pointer; if (pointer) ...` gives undefined behaviour.   It could test true (as in non-null).  It could test false (as in a null pointer).   Your program might reformat your hard drive, or any other possibility.   All three possibilities are equally correct according to the standard.   Your testing just happened to encounter one of them.  The same testing tomorrow might behave differently (or not) - because that's the nature of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why C++ Recognizes an uninitialized Raw Pointer (or say a daemon) as true?

The behaviour may appear to be so, because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Why the following code produces a SEGMENTATION FAULT!!!

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined, and that is one of the possible behaviours.

---

> But slightly changed following code doesn't

Because you don't read an indeterminate value in the changed program, and the behaviour of that program is well defined, and the defined behaviour is that the if-statement won't be entered.

---

In conclusion: Don't read uninitialised variables. Otherwise you'll end up with a broken, useless program.

Although a compiler isn't required to diagnose undefined behaviour for you, luckily high quality compilers are able to detect such simple mistake. Here is example output:

```
warning: 'pointer' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
if(pointer)
   ^~
```

Compilers generally cannot detect all complex violations. However, runtime sanitisers can detect even complex cases. Example output:

```
==1==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
```

---

Aside from reading uninitialised values, even if it was initialised, `if (pointer)` doesn't necessarily mean that you're allowed to indirect through the pointer. It only means that the pointer isn't null. Besides null, other pointer values can be unsafe to indirect through.

Comment: @M.AbdulRehman High quality compilers are available for free. It's time to start using them.

Comment: The real problem with reading uninitialised variables is that your code may work during your testing, but fail utterly for an end-user, and still work for you when you try to debug it.    Such things result in annoyed end users (they are given a program that doesn't work) and frustrated developers (because the program works when they test it,  and they keep getting bug reports from end users).

Answer (score 1):

Because your unitialized Pointer gets implicitly converted to a boolean.
Where 0 converts to false and every other value to true.

Comment: what is that, in implicit conversion, makes an uninitialized pointer a no-zero value instead of a zero - please explain

Comment: Actually *both* pointers, the uninitialised *and* the intialised one, are implicitly converted...

Comment: @M.AbdulRehman _"uninitialized"_ means a variable has not been initialised to any value.  Reading an uninitialized variable is Undefined Behaviour see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub .  C++ does not (usually) do extra work for you in case that work is not needed in the general case.